# Add class (odd and even) in html via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code example:

```
<section class="timeline">
    <article class="post ">
    <article class="post ">
    <article class="post ">
    <article class="post ">
</section>
```

Now i want to know how to add a class via javascript to article element.
For example:

1st article add class "left"

2nd article add class "right"

3rd article add class "left"

4th article add class "right"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want to do but very probably you don't need have any javascript you can write styles for odd and even childrens.

```css
.post:nth-child(odd) {
    color: green;
}
.post:nth-child(even) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="timeline">
<article class="post ">Article</article>
<article class="post ">Article</article>
<article class="post ">Article</article>
<article class="post ">Article</article>
</section>
```

Comment: It works but only for first 2 elements. Can you help me more ? I know it can work for all but i forgot.

Comment: Yes sure. Could you create code snippet with bug ?
If you are using the same html code as in your first code you need to fix missing </article>

compare my html and yours.

Comment: I found the bug. The code is good, problem was the the elements did not have same height and did not float:left well :) . Added height:410px to post element and now works fine. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure really what you want to do.I hope This will help you.

```
 let article = document.querySelectorAll('.post');
article.forEach((item, index) => {
    (index % 2 == 0) ?item.classList.add('odd'):item.classList.add('even')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Czlowiek is in my opinion the best answer, because it does not require Javascript to be enabled.

Next is that you should use ids. It is certainly a logical attribute for sections, but it is also very logical for articles.
But if you would like to do this with Javascript, then should you first get a handle on the section tag, with for instance:

```
var sec = document.getElementById('timeline');
```

Next can you loop through the childNodes of the section like:

```
var cntArticle = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < sec.childNodes.length; i++) {
   if(sec.childNodes[i].tagName === 'ARTICLE') {
       if(cntArticle%2 === 0){
          sec.childNodes[i].className += ' left';
       } else {
          sec.childNodes[i].className += ' right';
       }
       cntArticle++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Just in case.

after this script you will have <article class="postleft"></article> what will broke styles.

Comment: @CzłowiekFinŚpiewak: your statement would be correct normally, but if you take a look at the presented code, then do you see a space after each post. The code will therefor result in class="post left" and class="post right" respectively. I was aware of the space at the end of the class while writing this piece of code. :-)

Comment: Right but this piece should be universal imo. Another people who read this topic could copy-paste this code and have some redundant errors. ;-) Thanks!