# CSS: If class is odd/even, change margin

Tags: css, css-selectors, margin, alternate

I'm trying to alternate the margin to make images go zig zagged up and down. I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089944/add-class-odd-and-even-in-html-via-javascript) that came close, but applied the one change to all .brochureImg classes. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<div class="brochureBrand">
    <ul>
        <li class="brochureName hrDots"><a href="#">GP & J Baker</a>
            <li class="brochureImg first"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
            <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
            <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
            <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
            <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
            <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
            <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.brochureImg {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -90px;
    padding: 0 16px 150px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.brochureImg img {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #666666;
}

.brochureImg a img:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-top: -120px;
}

.brochureImg a img:nth-child(even) {
    margin-top: -60px;
}

.brochureImg.first {
    margin-left: 125px;
}
```

Comment: What exactly you wanna do? Can you provide a screenshot or describe it in more details?

Comment: you have only one image in the <li class="brochureImg">, and you are calling nth-child(even) on li>a>img...instead call it like this... .brochureName li:nth-child(odd) and .brochureName li:nth-child(odd)

Comment: I need more reputation to post an image. The images start on one line at margin-top: -90px. I want odd .brandImg to appear higher at -120px and even .brandImg lower from the starting point at -60px to have that alternating up down look. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so there were a few issues.

First, your html was badly formed, with nested `<li>` elements.  See my example below for how I fixed it.

Second, your css attribute wasn't the one you wanted, I think.  Instead of `margin-top` I think you need `top`.  This means where you want your item placed with respect to your nearest parent of `position: relative` or `position: absolute`.

Third, you css `nth-child` selectors were wrong.  The `nth-child` selector applies to the item which you put it on.  The `<img>` tag is always the first child, so instead I inferred that you wanted it on your `<li>` tags.

Lastly, a minor convenience: there is also the `:nth-child(2)` selector that you can put in your css, so that you don't need to add a class `first` (probably not very good html class name) to your `<li>` element that you want to indent.

I think this is what you wanted

```css
.brochureBrand {
    position: relative
}

.brochureImg {
    display: inline-block;
    top: -90px;
    padding: 0 16px 150px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.brochureImg img {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #666666;
}

.brochureImg:nth-child(odd) {
    top: -120px;
}

.brochureImg:nth-child(even) {
    top: -60px;
}

.brochureImg:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="brochureBrand">
    <ul>
        <li class="brochureName hrDots"><a href="#">GP & J Baker</a></li>
        <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
        <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
        <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
        <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
        <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
        <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
        <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you. I was trying to think of how it will display when the site goes responsive, but I guess that's still far ahead for me. Thanks again. Any general advice for planning for responsive?

Comment: A good place to start is to use an already existing css framework, such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and use that as your css template.  From there, there are a lot of options.  Perhaps reading [this](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/) or [this](http://www.uie.com/articles/strategy_for_responsive_design/) would be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

See, :nth-child pseudo-selector is applied to scope of elemenents which **are matching on the same level**. 
Let's see what your selector `.brochureImg a img:nth-child(odd)` does:

- First, it matches all `<li>` elements with `.brochureImg` which are **on the same level**.
- But then it goes deeped and selects `<a>` inside every `<li>`
- And finally it hits `<img>` inside.

Here, on this level of img, `:nth-child(odd)` is applied to only one image (only one image exist in every link) which obviously counts as odd (only one = first). Same goes for all others li, img. 
To hit `<li>` elements which you are positioning, you should use such selector:

```
    .brochureImg:nth-child(even) {
        top: -60px;
    }
```

And btw you have a typo in first `<li>` element - it's not closed :)

```css
.brochureImg {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 16px 150px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.brochureImg:nth-child(odd) {
  top: 20px;
}

.brochureImg:nth-child(even) {
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li class="brochureImg first"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
        <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
        <li class="brochureImg"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x175"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `.brochureImg a img:nth-child(odd)`, you are saying "Select odd `img` with `a` with `.brochureImg`".

But that is **NOT** what you want to say.

Do this, `.brochureImg:nth-child(odd) a img` and you will be saying "Select odd `.brochureImg` with `a` with `img`".

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/vwLh1ktr/).

Here is the snippet.

```css
.brochureImg {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -90px;
  padding: 0 16px 150px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
.brochureImg img {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #666666;
}
.brochureImg:nth-child(odd) a img {
  margin-top: -120px;
}
.brochureImg:nth-child(even) a img {
  margin-top: -60px;
}
.brochureImg.first {
  margin-left: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="brochureBrand">
  <ul>
    <li class="brochureName hrDots"><a href="#">GP & J Baker</a>

      <li class="brochureImg first">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/125x175">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="brochureImg">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/125x175">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="brochureImg">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/125x175">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="brochureImg">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/125x175">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="brochureImg">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/125x175">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="brochureImg">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/125x175">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="brochureImg">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/125x175">
        </a>
      </li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It raised all `.brochureImg` :/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Svvift/n3rLxhp1/1/) is your answer

```css
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
}

.box:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
.brochureImg a img:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-top: -120px;
}

.brochureImg a img:nth-child(even) {
    margin-top: -60px;
}
```

To this:

```
.brochureBrand ul li.brochureImg:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-top: -120px;
}

.brochureBrand ul li.brochureImg:nth-child(even) {
    margin-top: -60px;
}
```

The above selects the odd and even `brochureImg` classes.

Also, it's best to use more descriptive paths so not only is it easier to understand where the CSS is being applied, but you also won't be conflicting with other code you may have. Notice how I added `.brochureBrand ul li` before `.brochureImg`.

Comment: This had the same effect as the comment above. It raised them all, not odd even.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to target the li's not the images inside them.  Also you inner li's need to be enclosed in their own ul. I've found margin-top doesn't work well in this case. You need to use top and position relative:

```
 li:nth-child(odd){
     position:relative;
     top: -120px;
 }

li:nth-child(even) {
    position:relative;
    top: -60px;
}
```